# How to push string array to json object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new to typescript. please help to push the data so here it goes
Here the story goes I have string array and i need to push it to the json object

```
interface LocalIds {
    value: string;
    label: string;
  }

 const localIds = [
    { value: 'test', label: 'test' },
    { value: 'test2', label: 'test2' },
  ];


////////////// HERE in string array that data is coming ///////////
    const localIdentifiers: string[] = result.data.map((item: string) => item);


///////////// I want to push the string array data to json object with label & value////// 
// I experimented alot but giving some type error and all I am not getting 
    localIds.push({ label: 'abc', value: 'abc' });
 localIdentifiers.map(i => localIds.push(...localIds:{value:i,label:i}[])); //ERROR
```

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify` to convert an object to JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fixing last line as following

replace ; with , and remove [] at the end

```
localIdentifiers.map(i => localIds.push(...localIds, {value:i,label:i}));
```

also, you dont need `...localIds`, since it will duplicate current array every time element is pushed to array

Comment: also you dont need a `map`!

Comment: forEach is better solution here

Answer (score 2):

Half of your code does nothing useful

- `result.data.map((item: string) => item)` will do nothing
- using `map` when not returning anything inside it is pointless. At very least use `forEach` instead. or even better....

You should use `map` with `concat`:

```
interface LocalIds {
    value: string;
    label: string;
}

const localIds = [
    { value: 'test', label: 'test' },
    { value: 'test2', label: 'test2' },
];

localIds.push({ label: 'abc', value: 'abc' });
const finalLocalIds = localIds.concat( result.data.map((i: string) => ({value:i,label:i})) );
```

[Live example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDIHsFwDYEkAmAzsgN4CwAUMtcgG44CuEAXMoWFKAOYDclNybHABGEbK3acQvSgF9KlBOhDtBmHAWIBeZAG1+NEnUYtkAckjszAGkEixrCxCvJZ1g9SP1sTR5bAATDZ2ouLm-kGu7hQAunwUisqqUM4M2GDIOuRUNPhwYHCsugBEMOjoxdbFwnBQxTFyChTY6nhEAHQADgyEABYAFEZCoY4iCMHevuZjZq4AlPFKKhkwoDgYWG3aapua7UtYYP3IKYRpYO15Be0AtnCd-f3AEhzcc5kAfMiDkyzA1sMHMBZHN3gsmktCOhsBB2i0uP1ViB1q1NAsgA)